Intl dateStyle: 'short' 4 digits year in en-US
Consider:


let d = new Date()
console.log(`en-GB: ${d.toLocaleString('en-GB', { dateStyle: 'short' })}`) // 05/06/2024
console.log(`en-US: ${d.toLocaleString('en-US', { dateStyle: 'short' })}`) // 6/5/24



For some reason US only have 2 digit year which seems arbitrary and confusing, as well as no 0 padding. I can not find any documentation on the number of digits in a year for dateStyle: 'short', is there a way to force a 4 digit year in en-US locale ? (or alternatively a way using Intl to get mm/dd/yyyy ?)

Dumb as it may seem, that's a very common date style in the US.

We have a medical application showing both date of birth and procedure bookings .. 25 can theoretically mean 1925 or 2025 depending on context which is highly confusing and we cannot afford in the app

But there is a meaning to "short", no? If you want it differently, then could you not just pass another locale?

@trincot see my  comment above, is there a locale that will give mm/dd/yyyy ? and you want me to detect en-US and then switch to that local ? seems very convoluted :(

"detect en-US": I didn't get that point. Are you saying you want a different behaviour for other locales?

@Pointy  Dumb as it may seem, 2 digit years are common in the UK too.  Of course there will be some standards reason why it's 4 digit instead of 2 for UK, but at first glance does seem strange that it is.. :)

@Keith well dates are semantically very complicated.

You can set the format yourself:


let d = new Date()
console.log(`en-GB: ${d.toLocaleString('en-GB', { dateStyle: 'short' })}`) // 05/06/2024
console.log(`en-US: ${d.toLocaleString('en-US', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' })}`) // 06/05/2024



